Skin effect of wires with increasing frequency
When wiring RF inductors, how does skin effect affect the signal when larger wire (i.e. 24 AWG compared to 38 AWG) is used?
For context, I am building an AM radio(frequencies from 72 kHz to 1.3 MHz) and need a lot of inductors from several charts online, 37 gauge and above reaches the 1.3 MHz upper range, but has poor current handling (a few tens of mA at best). I would ideally use thicker wire, say 24 AWG for broader use (wire is quite expensive), but has a poorer frequency response (limit before skin effect is only <100 kHz).
If the frequency limit for, say 24 AWG is breached, how much does skin effect affect the signal (for LC filters)?

For receiver use, don't worry about current handling (as long as it's enough to avoid overheating).  Q factor is almost certainly more important.  Determine Q from required bandwidth, insertion loss and other network characteristics.
You can find Q for a simple helix geometry using a calculator such as: RF Inductance Calculator for Single‑Layer Helical Round‑Wire Coils, Serge Y. Stroobandt, ON4AA | hamwaves.com.  This is the most accurate one I know of online. In particular, it uses a waveguide model with various tweaks to accurately represent skin effect and resonances.
#37 is fine for most radio coils, but you may find the Q lacking for lower impedances (a few 100 ohms or below?), or without a core.
#24 is good for lower values (few µH and below). Litz helps at these frequencies but it's not at all required, and getting a Q over 100 doesn't take much size, or effort. Keep eddy currents down by spacing out the wires, and keep inductance high by using an aspect ratio (coil diameter to length) near 1.

Skin effect increases the AC resistance  of the wire, by decreasing the area available for current to flow. This reduces the Q of inductors. It reduces the sharpness and increases the loss of filters.
There are no frequency limits, the effects are progressive, so if somebody is quoting a limit for skin effect, they are making an assumption about what degree of change is acceptable.
In the range 100 kHz to a MHz or so, Litz wire tends to be used for winding high quality inductors, which mitigates against skin effect by permuting insulated strands of wire so that they are sometimes on the surface, and sometimes in the interior.
Once above a few MHz, Litz wire tends not to be used, as the loss due to the overhead in insulation starts to outweigh the gains to skin effect. Now you would use the largest diameter solid wire possible, given other constraints on the component. Silver plating is often used to gain an extra few percent in conductivity.
Note that an inductive component with N turns is not the same if wound with large or small diameter wire, as its physical size will change along with the wire size. This changes not only the inductance, but also self capacitance and SRF.
I read an interesting paper a while ago testing the use of simple stranded wire instead of Litz wire, relying on the fact that the resistance of contact between the strands was still orders of magnitude more than through the solid. Apparently it got more than half the improvement of moving from solid wire to Litz, for a much cheaper wire construction.
